# Populate Radio buttons from database

Tags: c#, .net, radio-button, bind

I am working with a `.net` application and I have a radio button list that needs to be populated from a table in my database. I am capable of getting the data and add them to list but the thing is that when display in the browser, instead of the data from the db it shows `utility.closingReason` that is the name of the class as you can see in my code.
Any idea where I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

```
 protected void rblContentTypesGetReasons_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string sqlQuery;

        sqlQuery = " SELECT REASON_DESCRIPTION";
        sqlQuery += " FROM CLOSING_REASON";

        dt = clsUtility.GetDataTableFromDB(sqlQuery, null);
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                objReason = getReason(dt);             
                //for (int i = 0; i < dtReturn.Rows.Count; i++)
                list.Add(objReason);                     
                    //RadioBtnReasons.Items.Add(new ListItem(dtReturn.Rows[i]["reason_description"].ToString() ));
                }                    
            }
            RadioBtnReasons.DataSource = list;
            RadioBtnReasons.DataBind();
        //RadioBtnReasons.Items.Clear();
    }
```

This is the code I am using to get the data from the database.

and the method:

```
   private object getReason(DataTable dt)
    {
        closingReason reason = new closingReason(dt);
        return reason;

    }
```

and the class `closingReason`

```
namespace Utility
{
    class closingReason
    {
       private System.Data.DataTable dt;
       private string _REASON_DESCRIPTION;

       public string REASON_DESCRIPTION
       {
           get { return _REASON_DESCRIPTION; }
           set { _REASON_DESCRIPTION = value; }
       }
       public closingReason(System.Data.DataTable dt)
       {
           // TODO: Complete member initialization
           REASON_DESCRIPTION = dt.Rows[0]["reason_description"].ToString();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: When you add objects to a List the UI will show the `ToString()` of the instance. Since you have not overridden `ToString()` it shows he name of the class. Anyway, as coded you will always get the first item in each loop iteration, I think you want to use the `row`, not `dt`.

Comment: Yes @Crowcoder i just noticed that i am getting always the first item as you said. Can you help me, how can i overridden ToString()?

Comment: If you just want the REASON_DESCRIPTON then you could just add that string to the list. But to override `ToString()` just start typing a new method "override..." and intellisense should show you `ToString()` as an option. Then you just return whatever string representation of your class you want.

Comment: @Crowcoder i just want REASON_DESCRIPTON. You thinking like this                 RadioBtnReasons.DataSource = list.ToString();  ?

Comment: No, `list.Add(objReason.REASON_DESCRIPTION);`. But of course you will have to fix your code so that it correctly creates a `closingReason` instance.

Comment: just got to complicated for me as a beginer. Thank you anyway @Crowcoder

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry for bothering you again but how can i use row instead of dt to loop in the datatable?

Comment: I didn't want to assume anything, but you could skip the class altogether if all you want is the string value to be data bound. You could just: `list.Add(row["reason_description"]);`. And I would make the list a `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.